# how to define target variable for linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I want to perform regression analysis on a dataset of dimensions 96x100. The columns represent the value for number of days(100) while the independent variable is the time. How can I perform linear regression as my target variable is multiple columns. Sample dataset is as:

```
time    day1    day2    day3    day4    day5    day6    day7    day8    day9    day10   day11   day12   day13   day14   day15   day16   day17   day18   day19   day20   day21   day22   day23   day24   day25   day26   day27   day28   day29   day30   day31   day32   day33   day34   day35   day36   day37   day38   day39   day40   day41   day42   day43   day44   day45   day46   day47   day48   day49   day50   day51   day52   day53   day54   day55   day56   day57   day58   day59   day60   day61   day62   day63   day64   day65   day66   day57   day68   day69   day70   day71   day72   day73   day74   day75   day76   day77   day78   day79   day80   day81   day82   day83   day84   day85   day86   day87   day88   day89   day90   day91   day92   day93   day94   day95   day96   day97   day98   day99   day100
500 6.07588E-10 6.13664E-10 5.89361E-10 5.95437E-10 6.31892E-10 6.37968E-10 5.83285E-10 6.01512E-10 5.83285E-10 6.1974E-10  3.03794E-09 -6.07588E-10    -2.43035E-09    1.21518E-09 2.43035E-09 6.07588E-10 6.07588E-10 -1.21518E-09    -1.21518E-09    0   3.03794E-09 1.82276E-09 -1.82276E-09    1.82276E-09 -2.43035E-09    -1.21518E-09    -1.21518E-09    -1.82276E-09    -1.21518E-09    2.43035E-09 1.82276E-09 -2.43035E-09    1.21518E-09 -6.07588E-10    -1.21518E-09    0   -1.21518E-09    1.21518E-09 -2.43035E-09    -2.43035E-09    3.03794E-09 -1.82276E-09    6.07588E-10 -1.82276E-09    3.03794E-09 -2.43035E-09    1.82276E-09 -1.82276E-09    0   0   1.82276E-09 -3.03794E-09    0   3.03794E-09 -1.21518E-09    -1.21518E-09    0   3.03794E-09 1.21518E-09 6.07588E-10 -3.03794E-09    1.21518E-09 3.03794E-09 0   6.07588E-10 -6.07588E-10    -6.07588E-10    1.82276E-09 -3.03794E-09    -1.21518E-09    1.21518E-09 1.82276E-09 1.82276E-09 2.43035E-09 3.03794E-09 1.21518E-09 1.21518E-09 -2.43035E-09    3.03794E-09 0   -1.21518E-09    -1.82276E-09    -1.82276E-09    1.82276E-09 -3.03794E-09    1.82276E-09 0   2.43035E-09 3.03794E-09 -2.43035E-09    -1.21518E-09    6.07588E-10 -1.21518E-09    6.07588E-10 3.03794E-09 0   -2.43035E-09    -1.21518E-09    -1.82276E-09    0
515 6.07588E-10 5.89361E-10 6.07588E-10 6.01512E-10 6.25816E-10 6.07588E-10 6.1974E-10  6.37968E-10 5.77209E-10 5.95437E-10 1.82276E-09 -3.03794E-09    0   2.43035E-09 1.21518E-09 -3.03794E-09    -3.03794E-09    -1.82276E-09    2.43035E-09 0   1.82276E-09 3.03794E-09 2.43035E-09 6.07588E-10 1.21518E-09 -2.43035E-09    -6.07588E-10    -1.82276E-09    -1.21518E-09    -2.43035E-09    1.82276E-09 -1.21518E-09    6.07588E-10 6.07588E-10 0   6.07588E-10 3.03794E-09 -3.03794E-09    -1.21518E-09    -1.82276E-09    0   -3.03794E-09    1.21518E-09 -2.43035E-09    -2.43035E-09    -2.43035E-09    1.82276E-09 -1.82276E-09    6.07588E-10 -3.03794E-09    -6.07588E-10    -1.21518E-09    3.03794E-09 -1.82276E-09    -6.07588E-10    -1.21518E-09    1.82276E-09 3.03794E-09 -1.21518E-09    -6.07588E-10    -1.82276E-09    -2.43035E-09    -1.21518E-09    1.82276E-09 3.03794E-09 1.21518E-09 6.07588E-10 -1.82276E-09    2.43035E-09 -3.03794E-09    0   -2.43035E-09    -1.82276E-09    -3.03794E-09    3.03794E-09 3.03794E-09 3.03794E-09 -6.07588E-10    -6.07588E-10    -6.07588E-10    -2.43035E-09    -2.43035E-09    -1.82276E-09    -3.03794E-09    -1.21518E-09    -6.07588E-10    6.07588E-10 -3.03794E-09    -1.82276E-09    6.07588E-10 2.43035E-09 1.82276E-09 1.21518E-09 0   0   1.21518E-09 3.03794E-09 2.43035E-09 6.07588E-10 3.03794E-09
530 6.07588E-10 6.01512E-10 6.1974E-10  6.13664E-10 5.95437E-10 6.31892E-10 6.01512E-10 5.77209E-10 6.13664E-10 6.25816E-10 1.82276E-09 2.43035E-09 1.82276E-09 -1.21518E-09    1.82276E-09 2.43035E-09 3.03794E-09 3.03794E-09 2.43035E-09 6.07588E-10 6.07588E-10 -6.07588E-10    2.43035E-09 0   1.82276E-09 6.07588E-10 0   3.03794E-09 -1.82276E-09    3.03794E-09 0   1.82276E-09 1.21518E-09 -2.43035E-09    -2.43035E-09    -3.03794E-09    1.21518E-09 -6.07588E-10    -1.82276E-09    2.43035E-09 3.03794E-09 -1.21518E-09    -6.07588E-10    6.07588E-10 2.43035E-09 0   -6.07588E-10    3.03794E-09 3.03794E-09 -1.82276E-09    3.03794E-09 1.82276E-09 6.07588E-10 0   -2.43035E-09    -3.03794E-09    -6.07588E-10    -2.43035E-09    -3.03794E-09    -1.21518E-09    1.82276E-09 6.07588E-10 3.03794E-09 6.07588E-10 0   3.03794E-09 2.43035E-09 0   -3.03794E-09    -3.03794E-09    1.21518E-09 -1.82276E-09    -3.03794E-09    0   -6.07588E-10    3.03794E-09 6.07588E-10 -2.43035E-09    -1.21518E-09    -2.43035E-09    -3.03794E-09    0   1.21518E-09 3.03794E-09 2.43035E-09 -1.82276E-09    -6.07588E-10    1.82276E-09 -2.43035E-09    1.21518E-09 1.21518E-09 -6.07588E-10    1.21518E-09 -3.03794E-09    -6.07588E-10    -2.43035E-09    -1.82276E-09    3.03794E-09 -2.43035E-09    3.03794E-09
545 6.07588E-10 6.25816E-10 6.07588E-10 6.13664E-10 6.07588E-10 6.01512E-10 5.95437E-10 6.07588E-10 5.95437E-10 6.01512E-10 3.03794E-09 1.21518E-09 -1.82276E-09    -3.03794E-09    3.03794E-09 1.82276E-09 1.21518E-09 6.07588E-10 6.07588E-10 -1.82276E-09    -1.21518E-09    3.03794E-09 1.82276E-09 2.43035E-09 1.21518E-09 2.43035E-09 -1.82276E-09    2.43035E-09 -3.03794E-09    1.82276E-09 -2.43035E-09    -6.07588E-10    3.03794E-09 2.43035E-09 1.21518E-09 3.03794E-09 -3.03794E-09    0   -1.82276E-09    2.43035E-09 -1.21518E-09    6.07588E-10 1.82276E-09 1.21518E-09 1.21518E-09 -6.07588E-10    -1.21518E-09    -6.07588E-10    3.03794E-09 1.21518E-09 2.43035E-09 -1.21518E-09    0   1.82276E-09 -1.82276E-09    1.21518E-09 1.21518E-09 3.03794E-09 -6.07588E-10    -1.21518E-09    6.07588E-10 -6.07588E-10    6.07588E-10 1.82276E-09 -6.07588E-10    3.03794E-09 -1.82276E-09    1.21518E-09 -6.07588E-10    1.21518E-09 1.82276E-09 -2.43035E-09    -2.43035E-09    -6.07588E-10    -6.07588E-10    6.07588E-10 6.07588E-10 3.03794E-09 -6.07588E-10    1.21518E-09 -6.07588E-10    2.43035E-09 -2.43035E-09    -2.43035E-09    -2.43035E-09    -1.82276E-09    0   -1.82276E-09    -3.03794E-09    1.21518E-09 3.03794E-09 1.21518E-09 3.03794E-09 -1.21518E-09    -3.03794E-09    -6.07588E-10    -1.21518E-09    1.21518E-09 -2.43035E-09    -6.07588E-10
600 6.07588E-10 6.13664E-10 6.07588E-10 6.01512E-10 6.13664E-10 6.01512E-10 6.1974E-10  6.1974E-10  5.77209E-10 5.89361E-10 1.21518E-09 -1.82276E-09    -2.43035E-09    1.82276E-09 3.03794E-09 -6.07588E-10    2.43035E-09 1.82276E-09 -6.07588E-10    -3.03794E-09    3.03794E-09 -3.03794E-09    -3.03794E-09    -1.21518E-09    -6.07588E-10    -1.82276E-09    1.82276E-09 3.03794E-09 -2.43035E-09    -2.43035E-09    -1.21518E-09    -3.03794E-09    -1.21518E-09    -3.03794E-09    -1.21518E-09    -3.03794E-09    -6.07588E-10    6.07588E-10 2.43035E-09 -6.07588E-10    -3.03794E-09    1.82276E-09 0   3.03794E-09 -1.21518E-09    3.03794E-09 -2.43035E-09    -1.82276E-09    -1.21518E-09    -1.82276E-09    -6.07588E-10    -1.21518E-09    1.82276E-09 0   0   -1.82276E-09    -1.21518E-09    -3.03794E-09    2.43035E-09 6.07588E-10 1.21518E-09 1.82276E-09 2.43035E-09 1.82276E-09 -1.82276E-09    1.82276E-09 0   3.03794E-09 1.82276E-09 1.82276E-09 1.82276E-09 -6.07588E-10    -1.82276E-09    -1.82276E-09    -6.07588E-10    -1.21518E-09    -1.82276E-09    3.03794E-09 -6.07588E-10    3.03794E-09 1.21518E-09 -1.82276E-09    -6.07588E-10    6.07588E-10 0   2.43035E-09 -2.43035E-09    -6.07588E-10    -3.03794E-09    2.43035E-09 -1.21518E-09    -1.82276E-09    1.21518E-09 3.03794E-09 1.82276E-09 3.03794E-09 3.03794E-09 6.07588E-10 1.21518E-09 -1.82276E-09
615 6.07588E-10 6.13664E-10 6.1974E-10  5.77209E-10 6.37968E-10 6.1974E-10  6.13664E-10 6.37968E-10 6.31892E-10 6.1974E-10  3.03794E-09 -6.07588E-10    6.07588E-10 0   1.82276E-09 -3.03794E-09    1.82276E-09 3.03794E-09 -3.03794E-09    6.07588E-10 2.43035E-09 3.03794E-09 -2.43035E-09    1.82276E-09 1.82276E-09 -1.21518E-09    -3.03794E-09    2.43035E-09 -2.43035E-09    -3.03794E-09    0   -2.43035E-09    -3.03794E-09    -6.07588E-10    -6.07588E-10    -2.43035E-09    3.03794E-09 3.03794E-09 -1.82276E-09    -1.21518E-09    6.07588E-10 -1.21518E-09    0   -1.82276E-09    0   6.07588E-10 3.03794E-09 -6.07588E-10    1.82276E-09 2.43035E-09 3.03794E-09 1.82276E-09 1.82276E-09 2.43035E-09 -3.03794E-09    -1.21518E-09    -1.21518E-09    1.82276E-09 6.07588E-10 6.07588E-10 -6.07588E-10    -3.03794E-09    1.82276E-09 3.03794E-09 -3.03794E-09    3.03794E-09 1.21518E-09 1.82276E-09 -1.82276E-09    -1.21518E-09    2.43035E-09 1.82276E-09 1.21518E-09 1.21518E-09 -1.82276E-09    1.82276E-09 1.82276E-09 3.03794E-09 -6.07588E-10    -1.82276E-09    1.21518E-09 1.21518E-09 -1.21518E-09    -2.43035E-09    -1.21518E-09    1.82276E-09 -6.07588E-10    0   2.43035E-09 -1.21518E-09    1.21518E-09 6.07588E-10 -1.21518E-09    1.82276E-09 1.82276E-09 1.21518E-09 6.07588E-10 -6.07588E-10    1.21518E-09 2.43035E-09
630 6.45127E-10 6.19322E-10 6.45127E-10 6.12871E-10 6.77384E-10 6.5803E-10  6.51578E-10 6.32225E-10 6.70932E-10 6.70932E-10 2.58051E-09 2.58051E-09 -1.29025E-09    -1.29025E-09    -3.22564E-09    1.93538E-09 3.22564E-09 -3.22564E-09    1.93538E-09 2.58051E-09 6.45127E-10 3.22564E-09 -1.29025E-09    0   3.22564E-09 6.45127E-10 -6.45127E-10    -6.45127E-10    -2.58051E-09    -1.93538E-09    -3.22564E-09    2.58051E-09 1.29025E-09 2.58051E-09 1.29025E-09 1.29025E-09 2.58051E-09 -1.29025E-09    -3.22564E-09    -3.22564E-09    1.93538E-09 -1.93538E-09    -3.22564E-09    -6.45127E-10    6.45127E-10 -1.29025E-09    -1.93538E-09    -6.45127E-10    6.45127E-10 -6.45127E-10    -3.22564E-09    1.29025E-09 2.58051E-09 -3.22564E-09    3.22564E-09 -1.93538E-09    -2.58051E-09    -2.58051E-09    -2.58051E-09    3.22564E-09 6.45127E-10 0   -3.22564E-09    3.22564E-09 -2.58051E-09    1.93538E-09 -1.93538E-09    6.45127E-10 6.45127E-10 3.22564E-09 -1.29025E-09    1.93538E-09 1.93538E-09 2.58051E-09 -3.22564E-09    0   -3.22564E-09    -2.58051E-09    1.93538E-09 1.93538E-09 -2.58051E-09    1.93538E-09 1.29025E-09 3.22564E-09 1.93538E-09 -1.93538E-09    3.22564E-09 -3.22564E-09    1.29025E-09 -1.29025E-09    3.22564E-09 -1.93538E-09    -3.22564E-09    -6.45127E-10    3.22564E-09 -3.22564E-09    -1.29025E-09    -2.58051E-09    -3.22564E-09    6.45127E-10
```

```
plt.scatter(reg.predict(X), reg.predict(X) - y, 
            color = "green", s = 10, label = 'Train data')
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to predict from this data?

Comment: @G.Anderson `the independent variable is the time`

Comment: i am trying to predict whether the water flow is normal or not. The values in columns day1 to day100 corresponds to the value of water flow on day 1 at 5:00am and so on. I have encoded the time as 500,515 for simplicity.

Comment: @QuangHoang "The variable whose value is to be predicted is known as the dependent variable and the one whose known value is used for prediction is known as the independent variable." (from [this site](https://explorable.com/linear-regression-analysis) ) so you have the data switched

Comment: @G.Anderson ha, you're correct. What was I thinking :-).

Comment: @QuangHoang I have tried to represent the results using matplotlib using the code I have edited in the post. Is it right or needs to be changed?

Comment: @Param so where's your target (dependent) variable? assuming that it's gonna be 0 (not-normal) and 1 (normal) or otherwise.

Comment: Happens to the best of us lol. To OP: This sounds like an outlier detection problem, rather than a linear regression problem. [Here is the sklearn page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) for common outlier detection use cases

Comment: All these cases are normal so the target value is 1. So how can we use this data to predict if it should be 1 or 0.

Comment: I think you want to regress water flow (dependent variable) on time (independent variable) and look at the errors (residuals) from your model to determine if it's normal. To do that, you need to convert your data to long format using pd.melt, which will convert your day columns into a single water flow column. You can also create additional independent variables like for day of week to improve your model if flow changes by day of week.

Comment: @SeanS that is exactly what I want to do. But being new to python I am facing difficulty in implementing it. So if I convert the data to a single water flow column how it will represent the water flow for different times on a particular day?

Comment: If you did something like this `df.melt(id_vars='time', var_name='day', value_name='water_flow')` it would also give you a new column with each day repeated for each set of times. So you would have a date column and a time column. You want to [dummy-out](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) your time column before you fit your regression at a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make time as the dependent variable(label) and Values at a different date, the features of your model(independent variable). You could use sklearn to conduct he multilevel regression quite easily:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X=np.array(df.drop("time",1))
y=np.array(df["time"])
clf=LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: what does this line of code do ```X=np.array(df.drop("time",1))``` ?